# How to call external class method from InlineButton attribute in Odin Inspector?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, odin-inspector

I'm tried to write a `UtilityClass` using **Odin Inspector**.

```cs
public static class UtilityClass
{
  public static void Select(Component obj)
  {
    UnityEditor.Selection.activeObject = obj.gameObject;
  }
}
```

And I tried to call that method on `InlineButton`.

```cs
[InlineButton("UtilityClass.Select", "Select")]
public Canvas canvas;
```

However, I get the following error:

> Couldn't not match the given string 'UtilityClass.Select' to any action that can be performed in the context of the type 'Test'. The following kinds of actions are possible:

Since Odin Inspector is implemented with reflection, I think it is a natural problem.

But, is there really no way to call an external method like the one above?

Comment: Why not add a method in the class?

Comment: @shingo Because it's a method called from every other class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Schwapo from SIRENIX responded.

---

Yes, if it's static you can just do

```cs
[InlineButton("@SomeExternalClass.SomeStaticFunction()")]
```

If it's not static you'll need a reference to the external class.

---